# Cannot GET image url multer (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am using `multer` library for file uploads on my React/NodeJS website.

This is the upload route on the backend:

```
var upload = multer({storage});

router.post('/events/upload', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const fileName =req.file.filename;
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/upload`
    let event = new Event({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        image: `${basePath}${fileName}`
    }) 

    event = await event.save()
    
    if (!event) {
        return res.status(400).send("Error in upload!")
    }

    return res.status(200).send(event)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.status(500).send()
    }
    
})
```

After I hit this endpoint, image successfully gets uploaded to `public/uploads` and the 'url' generated looks like this - http://localhost:5000/public/uploadv-a-i-b-h-a-v-.-j-p-g-1628524045320.jpeg

Now, I want to use the image url from the db to display to the client. But, when I access this url it says:

> Cannot GET /public/uploadv-a-i-b-h-a-v-.-j-p-g-1628524045320.jpeg

How can I display the uploaded image to the client? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You can see this [document](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) about serving static files in Express

Comment: I had already done this `app.use(express.static('public/uploads'))`. The image URL still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned image uploaded successful in public folder.

Then it means you have not served public folder in express I think.

```
app.use('/public',express.static('public'))
```

Add the above code before your express routing code to make it work.

Please check this [express static doc link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Now you can access the public folder.

Comment: I had already done this `app.use(express.static('public/uploads'))`. The image URL still doesn't work.